# Como colocar mascara no contact-form-7 do Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Não estou conseguindo colocar uma mascara no [*contact-form-7*](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) do Wordpress 4.5.3.

[image: contact-form-7]

Comment: Qual plugin está utilizando? Qual a versão?

Comment: A Versão 4.5... @Randrade

Comment: Não a versão do WP, e sim a do plugin. É o [Contact Form](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7)?

Answer (score 2):

No form adicione o `(class:telefone-mascara)`

```
[tel* seu-telefone class:telefone-mascara placeholder "seu telefone ou whatsapp"]
```

No plugin clique em editar:

[image: editar]

Vai aparecer um textarea com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Contact Form 7
Plugin URI: http://contactform7.com/
Description: Just another contact form plugin. Simple but flexible.
Author: Takayuki Miyoshi
Author URI: http://ideasilo.wordpress.com/
Text Domain: contact-form-7
Domain Path: /languages/
Version: 4.5
*/

define( 'WPCF7_VERSION', '4.5' );

define( 'WPCF7_REQUIRED_WP_VERSION', '4.4' );

define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN', __FILE__ );

define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename( WPCF7_PLUGIN ) );

define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN_NAME', trim( dirname( WPCF7_PLUGIN_BASENAME ), '/' ) );

define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN_DIR', untrailingslashit( dirname( WPCF7_PLUGIN ) ) );

define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN_MODULES_DIR', WPCF7_PLUGIN_DIR . '/modules' );

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_LOAD_CSS' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_CSS', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_AUTOP' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_USE_PIPE' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_USE_PIPE', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_CAPABILITY' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_CAPABILITY', 'edit_posts' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_WRITE_CAPABILITY' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_WRITE_CAPABILITY', 'publish_pages' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_VERIFY_NONCE' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_VERIFY_NONCE', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_USE_REALLY_SIMPLE_CAPTCHA' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_USE_REALLY_SIMPLE_CAPTCHA', false );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_VALIDATE_CONFIGURATION' ) ) {
    define( 'WPCF7_VALIDATE_CONFIGURATION', true );
}

// Deprecated, not used in the plugin core. Use wpcf7_plugin_url() instead.
define( 'WPCF7_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( '', WPCF7_PLUGIN ) ) );

require_once WPCF7_PLUGIN_DIR . '/settings.php';
```

Supondo que esteja usando um plugin jQuery, no final adicione isto:

```
require_once WPCF7_PLUGIN_DIR . '/settings.php';

register_shutdown_function(function () {
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".telefone-mascara").mask();
        });
        </script>
    ';
});
```

Se for Javascript puro:

```
echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
         var el = document.querySelector(".telefone-mascara");

         if (el) {
              //Adiciona a mascara
         }
    });
    </script>
';
```